# AngularJS - Handle repeated fragments like Header and Footer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to implement the header / footer in an Angular JS App. I was thinking of adding these as ng-include in the main index.html. However this would have worked if the header and footer are static pages. My case is slightly different... In Login page no header / footer is shown. Other pages depending on whether you are logged in or not, you have to show "Welcome user [ logout] " or "Welcome guest [ login ]".

I save the login information in the rootScope as well as set a boolean $rootScope.isLoggedIn on login. The biggest problem seems to be that the whole ng-include is not refreshed on a logoff. Hence divs with ng-show hide directives will not hide/show on change. Somebody suggested using ng-switch - it also behaves the same way.

If I move the header code inside individual views then everything is fine.

A similar question is here: [Refresh header page in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432370/refresh-header-page-in-angularjs)

Comment: It depends upon what expressions are used to change\hide the divs, are you watching on some properties etc. Provide some code template for the header and their binding expression.

Comment: Could you use ng-controller directive to give the headers/footers a controller with access to your $rootScope and add some hide/show logic?

Comment: BTW, putting stuff on $rootScope is equivalent to globals in "plain" javascript and not a very good practice, I'd recommend using a service for storing your "isLoggedIn".

Comment: @ivarni - thx. I started the app and I already have a LoginService... I should rename it to UserService and should have this there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a controller in the header/footer, as ivarni suggested. An example from an (experimental) app of my own:

In the index.html, the header will display a dynamically generated menu, login/logout etc:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"
    x-ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" x-ng-include="'app/main/navbar.html'"></div>
```

The `NavbarCtrl` builds the appropriate scope for the `app/main/navbar.html` template. The template would be as follows (taking into account your needs - and irrelevant details removed):

```
<div class="navbar-inner" x-ng-if="showHeader">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li x-ng-repeat="menuEntry in menuEntries">
                    <a x-ng-href="#{{menuEntry.path}}">{{menuEntry.display}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div x-ng-if="userData.loggedIn">
        Wellcome {{userData.userName}}!
        <a x-ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div x-ng-if="!userData.loggedIn">
        <a x-ng-click="login()">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the entire markup is hidden depending on the `showHeader` scope variable. It creates the menu dynamically (`menuEntries`). And depending on `userData.loggedIn`, the appropriate Login/Logout message.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what has happened. I coded almost the same but did not work... finally gave up. Then came back and redid - everything is fine!

Comment: Again it is not working after moving isLoggedIn from rootScope!!! Question updated...

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a Fiddle? It is the only way to help.

Comment: I've noticed you have prefixes of 'x' on your angular attributes. Why do you have `x-ng-controller` and `x-ng-repeat` instead of `ng-controller` and `ng-repeat`? Is it a custom prefix? Is there a benefit? Thanks

Comment: Strictly (very strictly) speaking, these attributes are not valid according to the HTML DTD. E.g. Eclipse displays warnings on those. However the DTD specifies that any attribute prefixed with `x-` or `data-` is legal. So writing `x-ng-if` instead of `ng-if` saves you some warnings on some tools. I rarely use this practice any more (as of 2015 - this answer is of 2013).