# Handling header and footer in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to implement the header / footer in an Angular JS App. I was thinking of adding these as ng-include in the main index.html. However this would have worked if the header and footer are static pages. My case is slightly different... In Login page no header / footer is shown. Other pages depending on whether you are logged in or not, you have to show "Welcome user [ logout] " or "Welcome guest [ login ]".

I save the login information and isLoggedIn in a service - then use HeaderCtrl controller to copy that to $scope. The biggest problem seems to be that the whole ng-include is not refreshed on a logoff. Hence divs with ng-show hide directives will not hide/show on change. Somebody suggested using ng-switch - it also behaves the same way.

If I move the header code inside individual views then everything is fine.

A similar question is here: [Refresh header page in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432370/refresh-header-page-in-angularjs)
[AngularJS - Handle repeated fragments like Header and Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286813/angularjs-handle-repeated-fragments-like-header-and-footer)

I have asked this question earlier but the answers did not help me when I moved the logged variable from the rootScope. The problem is my HeaderCtrl is only executing on a full page refresh. Not executing on Angular page navigation etc.

Here is the code:
index.html:

```
<body ng-app="greenhornApp">
    <div id="navbar" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"><div ng-include src="'views/partials/header.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-spacer visible-desktop"></div>
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="wrapper" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

header.js:

```
angular.module('greenhornApp')
  .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService', function ($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.isLoggedIn = loginService.isLoggedIn();
    $scope.session = loginService.getSession();
  }]);
```

header.html

```
<div>
  <div ng-show="isLoggedIn">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
More stuff here....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using ng-route and angular 1.2.0-rc3. I put a breakpoint in HeaderCtrl... it gets executed only when I do a full page refresh. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your `loginService.isLoggedIn()` is bound to a primitive value instead of an object, your `HeaderCtrl` needs to use `$watch` to monitor the variable and get the new value as it changes.

For it to work without a `$watch` you need to make sure an object reference is passed from your `loginService` to your `HeaderCtrl`.

I made two quick Plunkers that hopefully replicates your situation well enough to give some guidance:

With primitive and `$watch`: http://plnkr.co/edit/LvtVEE?p=preview

With object reference and no `$watch`: http://plnkr.co/edit/2u2ZDE?p=preview

Comment: Yesterday I ended up doing just that... adding watch on a broadcast and updating the model. I was feeling that the HeaderCtrl will be executed on all page navigations but it is not the case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you include the pertinent sections of code in your answer in case plnkr.co ever goes down?

Comment: Currently I use $rootScope.myFoo instead of more angularjs advanced ways involving factory, service, provider. Besider global namespace pollution, what’s the downside?

Comment: You have an unused </div>-Tag on line 13 in both of your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My original reasoning was wrong. Check tasseKATT's answer for that.

Here's is another way of communicating between controllers using angularJS broacasting mechanism

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyeVM/16/) just to show the basic idea.

```
var module = angular.module("demo", []);

function Header ($scope){

   $scope.userIsLoggedIn = true

   $scope.$on('DO_LOGOUT',function(event){
    alert('Header is updating log-status')
    $scope.userIsLoggedIn=false
   })
}
function Dynamic($scope){

 $scope.logout =function(){
    $scope.$emit('LOGOUT_REQUESTED')
  }
}

function Root($scope) {

$scope.$on('LOGOUT_REQUESTED',function(event){
    alert('Rootscope got logout event')
    $scope.$broadcast('DO_LOGOUT')
})   
}
```